# Fill numbers to the star shaped puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction

Fill in all the blank circle with numbers 1 to 6, so :

- Each lines of 6 circles, contains 6 different numbers.
- Each corner (consist of 3 greens circle) sums to 11.
- There is only 1 unique solution.

[image]

Comment: this reminds me of one of my question, though cant think of solving this without a computer :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Reasoning:

The only possible combinations for the green corners are:

> 1-4-6
>  1-5-5 - only if 1 is in the start corner
>  2-4-5
>  2-3-6
>  3-4-4 - only if 3 is in the star corner
>  3-3-5 - only if 5 is in the start corner

And we start from the top corner:

> The only valid combinations are 2-4-5 and 3-3-5
>  I decided to try with 2-4-5 because this will force me to put the 2 on the left side because of the 2 on the lower right corner
>  [image]

Next step

> Try to fit in the lower right corner because we already have a digit there
>  The possible combinations are 2-4-5 and 2-3-6.
>  The only valid one is 2-3-6 because of the 4 and 5 in the top green 3 cell corner.
>  Putting it like this:
>  [image]
>  will make us move to the lower left corner with the valid combinations:  1-4-6, 2-3-6, 3-4-4.
>  Trying them 1 by 1 resulted in contradictions.
>  So we back trace and change the order of 6 and 3 in the lower right corner
>  [image]

Next step, lower left corner:

> possible combinations: 1-4-6, 2-3-6, 3-4-4
>  Trying with 3-4-4 and 2-3-6 results again in conflicts.
>  Note: I'm not adding all my tries here because the answer will become boring and unreadable. And I don't want to upload 60 pictures.
>  Trying with 1-4-6.  (2 possible combinations). Just pick one. If it fails...try the other
>  [image]
>  In this combination we are left with the numbers 3 and 6 for the line from top to lower left. Obviously 3 goes on the upper empty cell because otherwise it will conflict with the line from upper left to lower right
>  [image]

Next: We can fill now the line that goes from top to lower right.

> only available digits are 1 and 3 and 1 obviously goes above 3.
>  [image]

Moving on to the upper left corner.

> We cannot use any combination that contains a 3 because there are already 3s on both lines that start from that corner. We cannot use 1-5-5 either because there is already a 1 on the horizontal line from that corner. So we are left with 1-4-6.
>  Obviously 6 has to be on the horizontal line.
>  And 1 cannot go directly in the corner because of the horizontal line
>  This make the lowest white cell be 5
>  [image]

Last step:

> We are left with 3 numbers to put in the upper right corner.
>  2, 4, 5.
>  There is only one combination that fits.
>  [image]

Answer (score 5):

It tooke me 2 hours to solve it and this is my answer:

> [image: Answer]

Comment: Since this is [tag:grid-deduction], can you add your solve process, or was this pure trial and error?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE :)